# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet

Tags: java, html, jsp

Al intentar correr una aplicacion web en java me sale ese error, ¿A que se deberá?

Servlet (Comics):

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import model.Cantidadcomics;
import model.CantidadcomicsFacade;


public class Comics extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    private CantidadcomicsFacade cantidadcomicsFacade;


    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet Comics</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet Comics at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
       request.getRequestDispatcher("./comics.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String id=request.getParameter("id");
        String nombre=request.getParameter("nombre");
        String ISBN=request.getParameter("isbn");
        String cantidad=request.getParameter("CantPaginas");
        String año=request.getParameter("AñoPublicacion");
        String autor=request.getParameter("autor");
        String categoria=request.getParameter("categoria");
        String editorial=request.getParameter("editorial");
        String $precio=request.getParameter("precio");
        int precio;
        try{

            precio=Integer.parseInt($precio);
        }catch(Exception e){
            precio=0;
        }
        if(id==null || id.isEmpty()){
            Cantidadcomics can=new Cantidadcomics(nombre, ISBN, cantidad, año, autor, categoria, editorial, precio);
            cantidadcomicsFacade.create(can);
        }
        request.getRequestDispatcher("comics.jsp").forward(request, response);


    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Clase (Cantidadcomics):

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author Asus
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "cantidadcomics")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cantidadcomics.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Cantidadcomics c")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Cantidadcomics.findByIdComics", query = "SELECT c FROM Cantidadcomics c WHERE c.idComics = :idComics")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Cantidadcomics.findByNombreComic", query = "SELECT c FROM Cantidadcomics c WHERE c.nombreComic = :nombreComic")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Cantidadcomics.findByIsbn", query = "SELECT c FROM Cantidadcomics c WHERE c.isbn = :isbn")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Cantidadcomics.findByCantidadPaginas", query = "SELECT c FROM Cantidadcomics c WHERE c.cantidadPaginas = :cantidadPaginas")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Cantidadcomics.findByAnoPublicacion", query = "SELECT c FROM Cantidadcomics c WHERE c.anoPublicacion = :anoPublicacion")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Cantidadcomics.findByAutorComic", query = "SELECT c FROM Cantidadcomics c WHERE c.autorComic = :autorComic")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Cantidadcomics.findByCategoriaComic", query = "SELECT c FROM Cantidadcomics c WHERE c.categoriaComic = :categoriaComic")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Cantidadcomics.findByEditorialComic", query = "SELECT c FROM Cantidadcomics c WHERE c.editorialComic = :editorialComic")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Cantidadcomics.findByPrecioComic", query = "SELECT c FROM Cantidadcomics c WHERE c.precioComic = :precioComic")})
public class Cantidadcomics implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_comics")
    private Integer idComics;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 30)
    @Column(name = "nombre_comic")
    private String nombreComic;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ISBN")
    private int isbn;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "cantidadPaginas")
    private int cantidadPaginas;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "anoPublicacion")
    private int anoPublicacion;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 30)
    @Column(name = "autor_comic")
    private String autorComic;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 30)
    @Column(name = "categoria_comic")
    private String categoriaComic;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 30)
    @Column(name = "editorial_comic")
    private String editorialComic;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "precio_comic")
    private int precioComic;

    public Cantidadcomics() {
    }

    public Cantidadcomics(Integer idComics) {
        this.idComics = idComics;
    }

    public Cantidadcomics(Integer idComics, String nombreComic, int isbn, int cantidadPaginas, int anoPublicacion, String autorComic, String categoriaComic, String editorialComic, int precioComic) {
        this.idComics = idComics;
        this.nombreComic = nombreComic;
        this.isbn = isbn;
        this.cantidadPaginas = cantidadPaginas;
        this.anoPublicacion = anoPublicacion;
        this.autorComic = autorComic;
        this.categoriaComic = categoriaComic;
        this.editorialComic = editorialComic;
        this.precioComic = precioComic;
    }

    public Cantidadcomics(String nombre, String ISBN, String cantidad, String año, String autor, String categoria, String editorial, int precio) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }


    public Integer getIdComics() {
        return idComics;
    }

    public void setIdComics(Integer idComics) {
        this.idComics = idComics;
    }

    public String getNombreComic() {
        return nombreComic;
    }

    public void setNombreComic(String nombreComic) {
        this.nombreComic = nombreComic;
    }

    public int getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(int isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public int getCantidadPaginas() {
        return cantidadPaginas;
    }

    public void setCantidadPaginas(int cantidadPaginas) {
        this.cantidadPaginas = cantidadPaginas;
    }

    public int getAnoPublicacion() {
        return anoPublicacion;
    }

    public void setAnoPublicacion(int anoPublicacion) {
        this.anoPublicacion = anoPublicacion;
    }

    public String getAutorComic() {
        return autorComic;
    }

    public void setAutorComic(String autorComic) {
        this.autorComic = autorComic;
    }

    public String getCategoriaComic() {
        return categoriaComic;
    }

    public void setCategoriaComic(String categoriaComic) {
        this.categoriaComic = categoriaComic;
    }

    public String getEditorialComic() {
        return editorialComic;
    }

    public void setEditorialComic(String editorialComic) {
        this.editorialComic = editorialComic;
    }

    public int getPrecioComic() {
        return precioComic;
    }

    public void setPrecioComic(int precioComic) {
        this.precioComic = precioComic;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (idComics != null ? idComics.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Cantidadcomics)) {
            return false;
        }
        Cantidadcomics other = (Cantidadcomics) object;
        if ((this.idComics == null && other.idComics != null) || (this.idComics != null && !this.idComics.equals(other.idComics))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.nombreComic + ": " + this.isbn;
    }

}
```

Codigo HTML (comics.jsp)

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Comics</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Agregar Comics</h1>
        <form action="./Comics" method="POST">
            <div><input type="hidden" name="id" value=""></div>
            <div><label for="nombre">Nombre Comic:</label><input type="text" name="nombre"</div>
            <div><label for="isbn">ISBN:</label><input type="text" name="isbn"></div>
            <div><label for="CantPaginas">Cantidad de Paginas:</label><input type="text" name="CantPaginas"></div>
            <div><label for="AñoPublicacion">Año de Publicacion</label><input type="text" name="AñoPublicacion"></div>
            <div><label for="autor">Autor:</label><input type="text" name="autor"></div>
            <div><label for="categoria">Categoría:</label><select><option>Acción</option><option>Drama</option><option>Comedia</option><option>Ciencia Ficción</option><option>Terror</option><option>Romantica</option>
                </select></div>
            <div><label for="editorial">Editorial:</label><input type="text" name="editorial"></div>
            <div><label for="precio">Precio: $</label><input type="text" name="precio"></div>
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea donde te indica el error? Parece que estás intentando hacer una operación ilegal, como sumar un número con una cadena o algo así. Pero sin saber la línea poco se puede hacer, por más que se analice tu código completo.

Comment: at model.Cantidadcomics.<init>(Cantidadcomics.java:105)
at controller.Comics.doPost(Comics.java:96) la primera hace referencia al constructor y la segunda al controlador

Comment: Tienes que buscar donde dice `Caused by ...` o edita la pregunta poniendo la traza completa del error.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Duplicate annotation for class: interface javax.validation.constraints.NotNull: @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull(message={javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}, groups=[], payload=[])

Comment: ¿En qué línea te dice que está el error? tienes varias anotaciones `@NotNull`

Answer (score 2):

---

Saludos,

> ¿A que se deberá?

Se debe a que estás intentando utilizar un constructor que lanza dicha excepción, de hecho, lo dice claramente:

```
public Cantidadcomics(String nombre, String ISBN, String cantidad, String año, String autor, String categoria, String editorial, int precio) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

Y lo estás llamando aquí:

```
Cantidadcomics can=new Cantidadcomics(nombre, ISBN, cantidad, año, autor, categoria, editorial, precio);
```

Lo que sucede es que parece que has insertado ese código utilizando el IDE y algunas veces el IDE genera excepciones como esa a modo de ejemplo, indicando que ese constructor no puede ser utilizado aún porque no ha sido programado (es fácil deducirlo porque lo dice el comentario al lado de la excepción).

Además, algunas veces es necesario utilizarlo, por ejemplo, la clase `java.util.Date` tiene el método `toInstant()` que permite obtener el objeto `Instant` de ese objeto fecha, sin embargo, la clase `java.sql.Date` (la cual hereda de la clase `java.util.Date`) no lo permite y si intentas utilizar ese método `toInstant()` te lanzará la misma excepción. Básicamente la excepción se debe para que nosotros los programadores sepamos a modo de información que ese método (o constructor en tu caso) no está disponible.

**La solución es bastante simple, sólo termina de programar tu constructor.**